# Are voltage followers pointless if it needs an external power supply?

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

I see a voltage follower is used when you have a mismatch in the impedances of two circuits. The voltage follower allows you to push more current/required current to the low impedance load.

However, the op-amp is being powered by an external power supply at the op-amps rails. So why don't you just use the external power supply to drive the load?

For example, if the load requires 2.5V at 20ma and you powering your buffer with a 10V external supply at its power rails, then instead of using the high impedance circuit why don't you just step the 10V supply to 2.5V since it can provide the required current fo the load?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKR0Rq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your example is a trivial case, where the output voltage is unchanging for all time. That is rarely the case in the real world.

Comment: "*... why don't you just step the 10V supply to 2.5V since it can provide the required current fo the load?*" How do you propose?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the question is not about if the output remains constant. The question asks why use a voltage follower if you using an external supply to power the op-amp, then why not just step down the external supply to power the load?

Comment: @Transistor adjustable linear regulator for this case. The LD1117...

Comment: if you eliminate the useless sinking capability from an opamp output and fit it stronger output transistor, you end up with a glorified linear regulator. obviously you can achieve the same goal easier using a dedicated linear regulator IC ( or switching regulator)

Comment: How do you "step down the external supply" if the required output voltage keeps changing? Isn't that much more complex than a voltage follower?

Comment: If you just want to have 2.5V at R3 and 20mA flowing through it then yes, you can accomplish this with an appropriately sized pullup resistor to your power rail. But the output is not regulated in any way so any variance in load will affect the output voltage.

Comment: Having a supply that can both sink and source current and that naturally tracks variations in VCC can be very helpful sometimes (for example as a termination bus for differential signals, or for single ended signals that must switch exactly at mid-rail).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not useless because you don't buffer power supplies with a voltage follower. You buffer signals sources.

If your input is a sensor one with a very high output impedance, it isn't going to be able to drive much current through its outputs without completely distorting its output voltage signal. It might not even be enough to drive an ADC. You aren't going to be able to just replace that sensor with a power supply.

The most common scenario that where you might buffer just a constant voltage is if you need a reference voltage. You can choose to make an entirely new power supply to do that, or you can just use a resistive divider to derive a voltage from a *regulated* supply you already have. But the output impedance of a resistive divider might be too high so you buffer it with a voltage follower.

A rarer instance is if you have a spare op-amp in your circuit which came along with a dual or quad opamp IC and need an odd voltage at a few mA to power something weird but don't want to spend extra money on another regulator. Then you wire it up as a voltage follower and either throw a divider connected to a regulated power rail, or zener diode on the input.

Comment: Yup, that application make more sense. Everyone provides examples with a fixed supply at the input. In this case 5V. So I struggled to see the use for this circuit. But when you use it for your application above it makes a lot more sense now. People should use better examples when teaching....

Comment: So a voltage follower in essence is a current booster?

Comment: @Joey It really depends what you mean by current booster (increases the current that CAN be supplied versus increase the current that IS supplied). The technical term is it decreases the output impedance so that the output voltage is better maintained even as more current is being supplied.

Comment: it allows you source more current as compared to the input?

Comment: @Joey Yeah......